# Laravel 5 - Using Class word as model name

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a model called Class and User.

my User model has this line of code.

```
use App\Class;
```

its giving me an error
"syntax error, unexpected 'Class' (T_CLASS), expecting identifier (T_STRING)"

but when I use other names its just fine.
could someone tell me why its not possible to use the word Class as a classname

Answer (score 2):

Class is a reserved word for php

[php reserved keywords](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php)

Try renaming it?

Hope it helps :)